# How to force a move out of a member of a temporary in a function in its return?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a holder class SqlContext for a result type of DiagnosticSQLResult like here:

```
template <typename T>
struct DiagnosticSQLResult
{
    bool success = true;
    string sqlError;
    T data;
};


DiagnosticSQLResult<ComplexType> GetSomeValue(SqlDatabase db)
{
    SqlContext<ComplexType> ctx(db, "sql query here");
    ctx.ForEachInSelect([&](SqlQuery& q){
        // code initializing result variable here
    });
    return ctx.result;
}
```

I would like to move out the ctx.result variable instead of copy constructing another instance when returning from a function. Is that possible somehow? As far as I understand, I can't just call std::move on it because it will be a dangling reference outside...

Comment: You're returning a value, not a reference. Just `std::move` it, it'll be fine.

Comment: Oh right, you're correct. It will move into a value and return that, thx. I am still trying to figure my way around std::move and it's been a bit frustrating >_<

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716647/rvalues-lvalues-and-formal-definitions). It might help.

Comment: Isn't this a situation where the compiler where the compiler can figure out to use a move by itself (assuming it's available)?

Comment: @john- No, it isn't. Returning `ctx` directly would make this eligible. But not `ctx.result`.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, thanks for information. Do you know a reference that explains this?

Comment: @john - Only the reference to rule them all https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.elision#3 - It's the requirement to use an id-expression. Member access is not included. Though I think if someone was brave enough they could write a proposal that makes it work with member access.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Hmmm, this stuff really does need a good tutorial. I'm struggling to understand the difference between copy elision (section 1), and the replacement of a copy by a move (section 3). The criteria seem very similar in the simple case of `return x;`.

Comment: @john - Section 1 is optional. It states that an implementation is allowed to do that, but not required. Section 3 is non-optional (and indeed has criteria that include the first section's criteria), an implementation must do the two stage overload resolution, regardless of whether or not the chosen overload ends up being used.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica OK makes sense, thanks.

Comment: You could declare `DiagnosticSQLResult<ComplexType> result;` inside the function and work on that in the lambda. When doing `return result;` you'd have NRVO, but perhaps that doesn't fit well into the sql-things.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of SqlContext class wrapping everything needed to work with sql in itself.

Comment: @Zeks Yes, I added a "_but_" at the end. I'm trying to find the documentation for `ForEachInSelect` but can't seem to find it.

Comment: This is a completely custom written class. You won't find it anywhere but my repository. I can link it if you want, but I suspect that ppl here will find the code subpar :)

Comment: @Zeks Perhaps adding a `accumulate`-like member function to that class that returns `decltype(ctx.result)` directly could be an option? Or, `SqlQuery` iterators and use the standard algorithms.

Comment: I guess I could technically just add a `decltype(ctx.result) returnValue()` function that does a move in itself so then outside func should catch that it's a temporary and prevent copying