# Why is std::forward needed when using forwarding references?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20

The forwarding reference is defined as follows:
"Forwarding references are a special kind of references that preserve the value category of a function argument, making it possible to forward it by means of std::forward."
(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)

By "preserve the value category of a function argument", I understand that the name of an argument variable whose type is a forwarding reference, has the same value category as in the function's invocation.
For example:

```
template<typename T>
void wrapper(T&& forwarded_argument) {
    some_function(forwarded_argument);
}

wrapper(5);
wrapper(my_int);
```

Here, the expression `5` in the first invocation is a prvalue, so as I understand it, the expression `forwarded_argument` (just the name of the variable) within `some_function(forwarded_argument);`, should also be a prvalue.
In the second invocation, the name `my_int` is an lvalue, so I would expect the expression `forwarded_argument` within `some_function(forwarded_argument);` to be an lvalue.
This would make writing this line as `std::forward<T>(forwarded_argument)` unnecessary, since in both cases, the correct overload of `some_function` would be called anyway, based on what I pass to `wrapper`.

I also think I don't fully understand what `std::forward` actually does. Here's a simplified implementation I found ([The implementation of std::forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501400/the-implementation-of-stdforward)):

```
template <class T>
inline T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}

template <class T>
inline T&& forward(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept {
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, "Can not forward an rvalue as an lvalue.");
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

As cppreference states (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), a cast expression to an rvalue reference to an object type, such as `static_cast<char&&>(x)`, is an xvalue. I don't see any mention of the value category of `x`, so I assume the value category of the whole cast expression is the same regardless. And the value category of a function call expression, whose return type is an rvalue reference to an object, is an xvalue. From this, it appears that no matter what I pass to `std::forward`, the value category of a call to `std::forward` will always end up being an xvalue.

Where is the mistake here? The conclusions in both parts of the question (about forwarding references and about `std::forward`) seem incorrect, judging by the way forwarding is usually done.

Comment: `_forwarded_argument` is always an lvalue. See: [Rvalues, lvalues and formal definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716647/rvalues-lvalues-and-formal-definitions)

Comment: So what exactly does the "preserve the value category of a function argument" part of the definition mean, if it's not that?

Comment: It means what it says: `std::forward<T>(arg)` has the same value category as the argument. But `arg` itself doesn't.

Comment: That `<int>` in the call to `wrapper` shouldn't have been there, it was my oversight, I edited it out.

Answer (score 1):

> Where is the mistake here?

It's here

> Here, the expression 5 in the first invocation is a prvalue, so as I understand it, the expression `forwarded_argument` (just the name of the variable) within `some_function(forwarded_argument);`, should also be a prvalue.

An *id-expression* (a plain *identifier*, to be specific) that refers to a function parameter is an lvalue. We need to cast it in order to get the value category of the argument to the function. And `std::forward` provides the correct cast based on the encoded value category in the deduced template argument.

A reference variable was bound to the argument (regardless of value category). Thus it now as a name, and the rule of thumb to go by is that things with a name are lvalues<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Just a rule of thumb. It's the general behavior for the most part. And is enough to get a feel for how forwarding works.</sub>