# Do I need to perfect forward arguments in these cases where the arguments are used directly in the function?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I thought to myself that I don't need `std::forward<T>(arg);` in my function because I wasn't passing the argument on to another function, I was using it directly. However then I thought even if I use it directly, by for example assigning it, or using it as a constructor argument then those each are function calls, respectively to `operator=` and constructor, which is a function call:

```
template <typename element_T>
    void push_back(element_t&& copy)
    {
        *_end = copy; // This calls operator=, which is a function
    }

template <typename ... ConstructorArgs>
void emplace_back(ConstructorArgs&& ... args) 
    { 
        
        new (_end) element_t(args); 
// Calls constructor, needs (std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...) ?

        
    }
```

Do I need the calls to `std::forward` in these cases?

Comment: If you want to pass them always as lvalues (and lose perfect forwarding), you don't, if you want perfect forwarding, you do.

Comment: @EVG So in other words they can lose their original type (their type at the call site) the as soon as it enters the context of the first function? With the term 'perfect ''FORWARDING'' I thought they only could lose their original type if you don't 'perfect forward' them to ANOTHER function.

Comment: To be more precise, they lose their [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) by unconditionally becoming lvalues. If you want to preserve the value category, you need to use `std::forward` on them.

Comment: I think [this](https://godbolt.org/z/cfM7dGT8j) exemplifies what @Evg says (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's a good example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression that is a name of a variable is always an lvalue. For example, in

```
1  template <typename T>
2  void push_back(T&& copy) {
3      *_end = copy;
4  }
```

`copy` in line 3 has the lvalue [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) no matter what type is deduced for `T`. Depending on how `operator=` in line 3 is defined/overloaded, this might result in selecting a wrong overload or in wrong type deduction.

Consider the following simple example (that follows the Ted Lyngmo's example from the comments section):

```
struct A {
    void operator=(const A&);  // (1)
    void operator=(A&&);       // (2)
};

struct C {
    template<class T>
    void push_back(T&& copy) {
        a = copy;
    }
    A a;
};

C{}.push_back(A{});
```

Which `A`'s assignment operator will be invoked here? One might expect (2) because `A{}` is a prvalue, but the correct answer is (1), because `copy` [is an lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56716647), and lvalues can't bind to rvalue references.

If we change the assignment to

```
a = std::forward<T>(copy);
```

then the expression `std::forward<T>(copy)` will have the xvalue value category and the (2) assignment operator will be called, as expected.

Placement new follows the same reasoning.